# How Do I Delete This Message After A While (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
let noiceEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(
          "ռօɮɛʟ",
          "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/d5/e2/c5/d5e2c5c0315e6b1f3cc30189f9dccd82.jpg")
        .setTitle(`<a:playing:799562690129035294> Started Playing`)
        .setThumbnail(song.thumbnail)
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .addField('Name', song.title, true)
        .addField('Requested By', song.requester, true)
        .addField('Views', song.views, true)
        .addField('Duration', timeString, true)
        queue.textChannel.send(noiceEmbed);
```

I want to delete this message after 30 seconds to prevent clutter.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextChannel#send()` returns a promise, so you can either resolve it using `then()` function or using async-await. `Message#delete()` has a timeout option, but it will de deprecated in the upcoming version. So delete the message inside a `setTimeout()` function.

Eg: Using **`then`** function:

```
let noiceEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Embed`)      
        .addField('EmbedField','Value') //your embed.
        message.channel.send(noiceEmbed)
        .then((message)=>setTimeout(()=>message.delete(),1000)); // 1000 is time in milliseconds
```

Eg:Using **async-await**: In order to using this, you need to make the whole client event as asynchronous.

```
client.on('message', async message=>{
    //other commands.
    let noiceEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Embed`)      
        .addField('EmbedField','Value'); //your embed.
        let embedmessage= await message.channel.send(noiceEmbed);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            embedmessage.delete()
        },5000);
    
});
```

Also if `queue` is your guild, then `queue.textChannel` is not a thing. `TextChannel` is a type of channel. So you in order to send this embed to send to a particular channel, you need to get the channel by id and then send the embed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, only use `delete` function

```js
queue.textChannel.send(noiceEmbed).then((message) => message.delete({ timeout: 30000 }));
```

Remember, the timeout is represented in `miliseconds`.
`1ms * 1000 = 1s`
`30000ms = 30s`

Answer (score 0):

You'll Need To Do A `.then`, And Then Put A Timeout Function.

```js
queue.textChannel.send(noiceEmbed).then((message)=> {
  setTimeout(function(){
    message.delete();
  }, 5000) //Milliseconds (5000 = 5 Seconds);
});
```